# Having multiple instance variables in rails controller action? (Rails best practices)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say for example I have two models, posts and category. Now say I want to make it so the from the category show page you can create a new post using the form_for method. To do this, you will obviously need access to the @category variable and a new instance of a post (@post). Is this acceptable code in the controller?

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @post = Post.new
end
```

Or is it bad practice to have two instance variables defined in the one controller action - and if it is, what would be the best practice for a case like this?

Comment: How are `Post` and `Category` related?  Could you show that as well?

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something like:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb

helper_method :category
helper_method :post

def show
end

private

def category
  @_category ||= params[:id] ? Category.find(params[:id]) : Category.new(params[:category])
end

def post
  @_post ||= Post.new(params[:post])
end
```

Then, in your views, just refer to `post` or `category` (not `@post` or `@_post`). The nice thing is you can remove the same logic from your new, delete, etc methods...

Answer (score 0):

Actions related to posts should be in the PostsController as much as possible.

Let's say the user is looking at all posts under the category "rails": `/categories/rails`

There's a button on that page to create a new post under the "rails" category, href: `/posts/new?category=rails`

This takes you to `PostsController#new` where you instantiate a new Post, validate the category param and build a view. This view could either be a new page, or a modal popping up.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with this. Although it might be a "best practice" there are definitely times where you might want to do it like OP is doing, such as replying to a forum thread via a quick reply box. It depends on the situation.

Comment: @Jake0oo0 Yes I probably should have elaborated that I was doing a modal popup here and wanted to know if this still was the best way to go about it